# JSF Issue with Refreshing a page

Tags: jsf, refresh

In a xhtml page I have a table with a list of item. For each item there is a button due to remove that item.
Everything appear to work properly, but if i press the "refresh" button of the browser, will be deleted another item of my table, and if I press the refresh again, will disappear another ones and so on.
I think there is somethink like that call again a kind of event "action  performed on the button" when I refresh the page.
How can I avoid this terrible issue?!

-xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:body>
    <h:form>  
    <p:dataTable var="c" value="#{viewContattoBean.contatto}">  
        <p:column headerText="Nome">  
            <h:outputText value="#{c.contattoid}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Telefono">  
            <h:outputText value="#{c.numero}" />  
        </p:column>  
        <p:column headerText="Elimina">  
            <h:commandButton action="#{viewContattoBean.removeContatto(c)}" value="Elimina" />  
        </p:column>  
    </p:dataTable>  
    </h:form>  
    </h:body>
</html>
```

-here is the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="viewContattoBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ViewContattoBean {
    @EJB
    private GestoreContattiLocal ejb;

    private ContattoDTO[] contatto;

    public ContattoDTO[] getContatto() {
                    System.out.println(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
        return ejb.getAll(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
    }

    public void setContatto(ContattoDTO[] contatto) {
        this.contatto = contatto;
    }

    public void removeContatto(ContattoDTO contatto){
        System.out.println("remove: " + contatto.getUtenteid() + ", " + contatto.getContattoid());
        ejb.removeContatto(contatto.getUtenteid(), contatto.getContattoid());
    }

}
```

Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page the last server call is repeated.
So when you push the delete button a post is made to the server, the refresh button repeat this action.
This problem is solved with [Redirect-After-Post](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post) pattern.
To avoid this behavior you should perform a redirect, by using the get param `faces-redirect=true`.
So your bean should be modified as follows:

```
@ManagedBean(name="viewContattoBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ViewContattoBean {

    //...

    public String removeContatto(ContattoDTO contatto){
        System.out.println("remove: " + contatto.getUtenteid() + ", " + contatto.getContattoid());
        ejb.removeContatto(contatto.getUtenteid(), contatto.getContattoid());
        return "pageName?faces-redirect=true"  
    }

}
```

To deepen the problem read this article about [POST-REDIRECT-GET and JSF 2.0](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/post_redirect_get_and_jsf).

Answer (score 0):

I tryed with this code like u said but is exactly behaving the same as before, with the same issue...

```
public String removeContatto(ContattoDTO contatto){
        System.out.println("remove: " + contatto.getUtenteid() + ", " + contatto.getContattoid());
        ejb.removeContatto(contatto.getUtenteid(), contatto.getContattoid());
        return "user/view.hxtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

in the html page i have:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{viewContattoBean.removeContatto(c)}" value="Elimina" />
```

Thanks for answering, by the way, and sorry for my late answer.

Samuele

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem could be that i redirect to the same page as before?! 
P.s maybe i should say that when i press the refresh button appears a message asking me:

> "to render again the webpage is necessary to resend throught the webbroswer the information  already sended."